# Resolving controllers using Castle Windsor with dynamically loaded DLLs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll, castle-windsor

After loading the web application, Castle Windsor cannot find the controllers. The controller for path '' was not found or does not implement IController. When I look into the kernel (in the CustomControllerFactory) I see that all the controllers are correctly registered.

The main MVC application loads 3 other DLL's. When we directly reference the DLL's in Visual studio and load the Plugin types it is working. But when dynamically loading it, it says fails. When I request a URL the context being passed into the GetControllerInstance is correct but the Type parameter is null.

I am loading an assembly using Assembload.LoadFrom.Then I retrieve the Types foreach module, which is a subclass of Plugin. Which results in the 3 types I have.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(module);

Type pluginType = assembly.GetTypes()
                    .Single(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Plugin)));
```

Then I create an instance of the Plugin, which I use to register the routes.

```
(IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(type))
```

RegisterRoutes:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes, IEnumerable<IPlugin> plugins)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        var pluginRouteDefaults = new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional};
        foreach (var plugin in plugins)
        {
            var context = new AreaRegistrationContext(plugin.Area, routes);
            context.MapRoute(plugin.Area, $"{plugin.Area}/{{controller}}/{{action}}/{{id}}", pluginRouteDefaults, plugin.GetControllerNamespaces().ToArray());
        }

        routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Default",
              url: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { area = "Framework", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
              namespaces: new string[] { "Web.Framework.Controllers" }
              );
    }
```

CustomControllerFactory:

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public VlcControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this._kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        _kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext context, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            return base.GetControllerInstance(context, controllerType);
        }
        try
        {
            return (IController)_kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
        }
        catch
        {
            return base.GetControllerInstance(context, controllerType);
        }
    }
}
```

Registering the controllers. After doing this I can see that in the Modules window in Visual Studio the DLL's are loaded. Also the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() says that the DLL's are loaded.

```
container.Register(
            Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IController>().LifestyleTransient());
```

MvcApplication class where I locate the Dll's.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var directories = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Projects\main\modules").Where(x => !x.EndsWith("Framework"));
        string subPath = GetSubPath();

        List<Type> pluginTypes = GetPluginTypes(directories, subPath);
        var plugins = GetIPlugins(pluginTypes);
        Launcher.CreateWindsorContainer(plugins.ToArray());
    }

    private static List<IPlugin> GetIPlugins(List<Type> pluginTypes)
    {
        List<IPlugin> plugins = new List<IPlugin>{new MvcInstaller()};

        pluginTypes.ForEach(type => plugins.Add((IPlugin) Activator.CreateInstance(type)));
        return plugins;
    }

    private static List<Type> GetPluginTypes(IEnumerable<string> directories, string subPath)
    {
        List<Type> pluginTypes = new List<Type>();

        foreach (string directory in directories)
        {
            string module = Directory.GetFiles(directory + subPath).SingleOrDefault(x => x.EndsWith("Plugin.dll"));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(module))
            {
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(module);
                Type pluginType = assembly.GetTypes()
                    .Single(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Plugin)));
                pluginTypes.Add(pluginType);
            }
        }
        return pluginTypes;
    }

    private static string GetSubPath()
    {
        #if DEBUG
        var subPath = @"\bin\Debug\";
        #else
        subPath = @"\bin\Release\";
        #endif

        return subPath;
    }
}
```

When I omit this code and directly reference the other Dll's and do the following:

```
Launcher.CreateWindsorContainer(new PluginA(), new PluginB(), new MVCPlugin());
```

Then it works perfect, but with my loading of Dlls, the resolving of the controllers is failing. Why can Castle Windsor not find the Types when requesting a Controller?

Comment: How are you registering the components in Windsor?

Comment: Edited my question. When debugging that line I can see that the controllers are added and can be resolved.

Comment: Is your custom `GetControllerInstance` being called?

Comment: Yes, but when it is getting called the controllerType is null. I can see in the context that the correct area/controller/view is being requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is not the Windsor resolution of your controllers. The `DefaultControllerType.GetControllerType()` method is probably returning `null`, because you didn't add the assemblies to the `BuildManager` (with `BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly(assembly)`). Keep in mind you can only call this before application start, so you need to use `[assembly:PreApplicationStartupMethod(typeof(...SomeType), "PublicStaticVoidMethodOnSomeType")`.